# How to get AUTO_INCREMENT ID from inserted record in Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate3.0 with mysql as DB, In one of the scenario from my project, I have to insert a record with default values. After successful insertion, I have to retrieve the `auto_generated id` of inserted record, so that I can use it for next query?

There may be multiple records getting inserted in same table. So is there any safe way to retrieve AUTO_GENERATED ID?

Comment: Are you using Entity to Persist?

Comment: Then after persisting the entity, the ID must be available in the entity itself. You can get it with getId() (Assuming getID is getter for the primary key)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
session.persist(myEntity);
myEntity.getId();
```

Comment: "this" keyword also use instead of "myEntity"